# The button icons in the Measure dialog box disappear!

Tags: arcobjects

My development environmnet is vs2008 c# + AE 9.3.
I use the follow codes to implement the **measure** tool:

```
        ICommand cmdMeasure;
        cmdMeasure = new ControlsMapMeasureToolClass();
        cmdMeasure.OnCreate(MapControl.Object);
        MapControl.CurrentTool = cmdMeasure as ITool;
```

But When the Measure dialog box shows,the button icons is disappear.As shows in the picture.I can't solve this problem. Please help me, please!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the measure tool to come up that's not the way to do it. You're creating a new one which could explain the loss of buttons.

The way to do it is:

```
ICommandBars commandBars = application.Document.CommandBars;
ICommandItem cmdMeasure;
UID MeasureUID = new UID();
MeasureUID.value = "esriControls.ControlsMapMeasureTool";
cmdMeasure = commandBars.Find(MeasureUID, false, false);
ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = cmdMeasure;
```

For an ArcMap addin you can access the application object from `ArcMap.Application`, for a non-addin type you would have got your application previously from the `OnCreate`.

Some links for your reference:

[Get a command on the command bars](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000031000000)

[IApplication.CurrentTool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000037000000)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have solve this problem by refer：http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/12467-ControlsMapMeasureToolClass-button-visibility-problem-deals-with-EnableVisualStyles?p=387871#post387871